# How to display custom info bar in outlook 2007 message window?

Tags: c#, outlook, message, add-in, customization

I want to display a custom info bar in my outlook message.

Something like the screenshots here:
http://www.sendshield.com/product/solution.php#

I have seen outlook form regions, and I dont think its a form region. If it is, then I am in trouble, as the only way I think to do is, and I may be wrong, is to use Replace type, in which case I have to handle al the possible scenarios for an outlook email, which I dont want to.

Any pointers in the right direction will be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: mmb, it may be a form region, have you installed it and taken a look at the registry? as if its formregion you will see it there.
check out or around 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\FormRegions

Comment: I have checked the registry, and its an outlook addin, no form region entry.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.

Check this article. Wealth of tips, on how to accomplish this.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/additional_panel_Outlook.aspx

Needed some tweaks, obviously, and I was able to show my window in message window.

Thanks anyway.